# limit the amount of DOM elements according target device RAM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-applications, ram

I created horizontally scrollable sections with Flexbox. The server can return thousands of sections.

The problem is that target device has a limited amount of RAM.

Is there any possible way so that I can limit the amount of DOM elements and prevent this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla javascript in the browser runs in a sandbox so it doesn't have access to system resources etc, so you can't detect how much RAM device has.

Just my 2p but returning 1000 of items to the user would be bad UX, a better design approach could be more effective solution